# Why is semi-locally simply connected defined this way?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, connectedness, fundamental-groups

I would like to know why we define a space $X$ to be semi-locally simply connected if

$\forall p\in X \exists U\ni p: i(\pi_1(U))=0\subset \pi_1(X)$ (SLSC),

where $i$ is induced by $U\hookrightarrow X$. My question is: why isn't the definition

$\forall p\in X \exists U\ni p: \pi_1(U)=0$ (SLSC')

sufficient? Of course I can imagine neighbourhoods of a point for which this distinction makes a difference. However, I cannot imagine any space where there is a point for which no environment has vanishing $\pi_1$, but there is an environment with vanishing image of $\pi_1$ in the fundamental group of $X$.

Comment: We need that definition beecause it precisely captures what is needed for the construction of universal covers, for example. Your alternative is not a necessary condition for that.

Comment: (In English we say *neighborhood* for what you are calling *environment*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [semi-locally simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-locally_simply_connected) has a good example of a space that is semi-locally simply connected but not locally simply connected: the cone over the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring).

The thrust of this example is that small open neighborhoods will generally contain non-contractible circles—but these circles can be contracted in $X$ by collapsing them to the cone point.

This space still satisfies your second definition, which is a bit weaker than locally simply connected, but this can be fixed, for example by gluing another Hawaiian earring to the cone point.

Comment: Thank you for this example!